# "should think" vs "think" - What's the difference?

Tags: meaning

Are they just actually the same?

1. I'm not sure how much the trip will cost, I should think $500 will be ample.
2. I'm not sure how much the trip will cost, I think $500 will be ample.

Comment: If you were to omit the "I'm not sure how much the trip will cost" and let the second clause stand alone, "should" adds a bit more willingness or invitation to hear why they should think otherwise.  Without the "should" qualifier,  it might be easier to read the declarative statement as a more firm conclusion.  But, 'should' is also a bit formal sounding - it is not common in everyday speech of a averagely educated person or character on screen.  HOWEVER, with the first clause, it ONLY sounds formal and a bit snooty as the uncertainty was already established.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In all honesty, there is no difference between the two. When both are said, they are interpreted the same. The same is presented in the following phrases:

> Do you care to join me this afternoon?
>
> Would you care to join me this afternoon?

Although, the slight difference between phrases in both your example and my example is **one is interpreted more formal than the other in certain situations**.